# Relative imports in Python3, 'cannot import name'

Tags: api, flask, python-3.4

I am building a flask-based API using code from other projects as well and my `/app_v1/rotues.py` file includes the file `from __init__ import api`, which however causes an error if called from `/run.py`, but not otherwise. The precise error I get is:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'api'`

I am not sure how to proceed, as replicating on a smaller project and the same error did not re-occur.

Things I have tried:

- All the typical permutations of `.__init__` or `..api_v1.__init__` etc., this usually results in the error `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`
- I can get the code to run if I include a designation for the API Blueprint (from Flask), but then the API does not register all the routes and therefore it is not useful.
- Rolling back, but I ran into the issue that some of of the code was in Python cashed, so that did not quite work either and I did not want to go too far back.

Perhaps the rough file structure is helpful:

```
.
|-app_v1
|  |-__init__.py
|  |-routes.py
|-run.py
```

Comment: try `from app import api` or maybe `from api_v1.app import api`.

Comment: I tried it and the former gives me the server back, but as in point 2, I cannot get it to find the paths. So any request I send to the API gets a 404.

Comment: Feel a bit puzzled about your description, could you please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It will help us find the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to write the following in your `__init__.py` file

```
from routes import *
```

when you write this and write the following in your run.py, it should work.

```
from app_v1 import routes
```